# Array merging (unsigned char[16] to unsigned long) template error after update toolset 142 ->143 (VS2022)

Tags: c++, c++17, visual-studio-2022

I have a set of errors appearing after the update from toolset 142 to 143 with a c++ (c++17) project in VS2022 (17.5.2).

[image: errors 143]

I am using those functions to do the type conversion:

```
#ifndef ul
#define ul unsigned long
#endif
#ifndef byte
#define byte unsigned char
#endif

template<class T>
T ToType(const byte* x)
{
    T value{};
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof T; i++)
        value += ((long)x[i] & 0xffL) << 8 * i;
    return value;
}

template<class T>
T ToTypeRevEndian(const byte* x)
{
    T value{};
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof T; i++)
        value = (value << 8) + (x[i] & 0xff);
    return value;
}
```

and I am using `ToType` in particular this way:

```
//SmartInfo->UnsafeShutdowns is uchar[16]
//SmartShortInfo.UnsafeShutdowns is unsigned long (ul)

SmartShortInfo.UnsafeShutdowns = ToType<ul>(SmartInfo->UnsafeShutdowns);
```

I believe this is where the template was used and where the compiler started to complain (after update), while is was not complaining before and the code was working well / tested and passed.

I believe my code is correct. Nevertheless, do I do something wrong ? should I file a bug to MSFT ? Which workaround should I sollicit if it's the compiler or should I downgrade the toolset ?

**Repro example**

header:

```
#pragma once

namespace NVMe
{
    using ull = unsigned long long;
    using ul = unsigned long;
    using byte = unsigned char;
    using ushort = unsigned short;
}

template<class T>
T ToType(const NVMe::byte* x)
{
    T value{};
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof T; i++)
        value += ((long)x[i] & 0xffL) << 8 * i;
    return value;
}

template<class T>
T ToTypeRevEndian(const NVMe::byte* x)
{
    T value{};
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof T; i++)
        value = (value << 8) + (x[i] & 0xff);
    return value;
}
```

cpp:

```
#include "myheader.h"

int main()
{
    NVMe::byte A[2]{2,3};
    NVMe::ushort A_ {};
    NVMe::byte B[16]{};
    NVMe::ul B_{};

    A_ = ToType<NVMe::ushort>(A) - (NVMe::ushort)7;
    B_ = ToType<NVMe::ul>(B);
}
```

errors:

[image: errors repro]

Comment: Seems like your `define`s are causing problems in the standard library headers. Don't do that.

Comment: Looks like you tripped over one of the rare times brackets really do help out the `sizeof` operator.

Comment: Getting ahead of myself and voting to reopen, but you should add the full plaintext of the errors you're seeing to ensure we're all on the same page.

Comment: Side note: Throwing the code at another compiler will give you different error messages. Often one of the alternate compilers will give more or better information. In this case clang pretty much tells you exactly what went wrong: https://godbolt.org/z/5469z3Tz9 It's worth using a tool like Compiler Explorer or a collection of compilers on your development system to help narrow down problems.

Comment: @user4581301 I added the errors message; indeed it was the parenthesis.

Comment: In Visual Studio The error list is an executive summary of the errors. Sometimes more complete and better information can be found in the raw output found in the Output tab right beside the Error List tab. Plus it's all plain text so you don't have to much around with screenshots.

Comment: @user4581301 I know, thanks. The screenshot however has error lines.

Comment: Handy reading: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4581301)

Comment: @user4581301 I provided both so I do not see the problem, furthermore, how would you provide code line and relative errors ? SO does not provide such possiblity

Comment: I only see images of the errors. The full build output includes line numbers for all of its diagnostic messages. We seem to be having some sort of communication problem because I'm clearly not getting the point across.

Comment: @user4581301 You seems to critisize the presence of images, but they provide pieces of information that can't be simply provided with text, beside, the code is present as text also, so I do not see the point of your suggestions of not using images. If you have a good alternative to those images, I would be very curious and interested.

Comment: I don't see how the error  information cannot be provided as text. I'd paste in the contents of the output tab, but I don't have a copy of visual studio new enough to consider this code to be an error. Best I can do is a godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/ojqPf78d4 . Plain text that everyone can see or have a textreader process for them, line numbers are present and much more information. Not that it's particularly useful information in this case, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof`'s operand must be either an expression (not necessarily with parentheses) or a parenthesized type-id. A type can't be given to it without parentheses. So `sizeof T` must be `sizeof(T)` instead. That has always been the case in ISO standard C++.

Presumably MSVC allowed a non-parenthesized type-id regardless in non-standard-conformance mode (`/permissive`), but newer MSVC versions default to standard-conformance mode (in particular in C++20 or later mode).

---

Old answer for the first part of the question:

`#define`ing an identifier used in the standard library causes undefined behavior if any standard library header is included.

Since C++17 `byte` is an identifier used in the standard library (for [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte)) and so your `#define byte unsigned char` causes undefined behavior.

If you need to introduce a type alias, never use `#define`. Use a `using`-declaration instead:

```
using byte = unsigned char;
```

and better also limit its scope to one of your own namespaces, so that it can't conflict with a name in the global namespace scope.